# how do i adjust this slice and replace React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I am trying to set the maximum length of an input through js because I need to do it like this, and in part it already works, I need it to print with commas but not to count them, this is my code:

```
<input  onInput={ (evt) => this.handleChange(evt)} />
```

if the maxlenght is 8 then until I press 8  numbers it prints me like this:
12,222,222
but if I press one more number, 8 are still preserved but the format is damaged and it prints like this:
12222222

```
 private handleChange(evt) {
        evt.target.value=evt.target.value.replace(/,/g,"").slice(0, this.maxLength)
        const element = evt.target ? evt.target.value : '';
         if (this.type == 'decimal') {
          const value= this.formatDecimal(element,this.maxLength, this.maxDecimals, this._separatorDecimal, this.separator);
        }
    }
    
   formatDecimal(input, maxLength, maxDecimals, separator, separatordigit) {
      var input_val = input;
      if (input_val === separator) {
        input_val = '';
      }
      input_val = this.formatNumber(input_val, maxLength, separatordigit);
      input_val = "" + input_val;
    }
    return input_val;
  }
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for your Component?

Comment: I notice you modified the event's value directly. Not a good practice I would say

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems to be working when I made the input controlled and made value part of the state of the component.

Main things to note are:

You shouldn't mutate the input's value directly. That could cause some issues.

You should make value changes that you expect to be related to the DOM in component state rather than component properties. Properties won't cause the component to re-render and sync to the dom.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  maxLength = 14;
  type = 'decimal';
  state = { value: '' };
  separator = ','
  handleChange = (ev) => {
  const element = ev.target.value.replace(/,/g,'').slice(0,this.maxLength);
    if (this.type == 'decimal') {
      this.setState({value:this.formatDecimal(
        element,
        this.maxLength,
        this.maxDecimals,
        this._separatorDecimal,
        this.separator
      )});
    }
  };

  formatDecimal(input, maxLength, maxDecimals, separator, separatordigit) {
    var input_val = input;
    if (input_val === separator) {
      input_val = '';
    }
    input_val = this.formatNumber(input_val, maxLength, separatordigit);
    input_val = '' + input_val;

    return input_val;
  }

  formatNumber(n, maxLength, separator) {
    n = n.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    n = n.substring(0, maxLength);
    // format number 1000000 to 1,234,567
    return n.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, separator);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```